# Why my modal doesn't render on the screen when I click on image?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I wrote a simple implementation on React that include an array of Projects.
Eeach projects has is own properties.
I wrote a modal that everytime someone click on an image it has to render on the screen.
right now the modal doesn't appears on the screen.
i try to figure out why and what is problem but unfortunately i cant.
here is the implementation and the CSS:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Showarma from "../Assets/Showarma.png";
import SimonGame from "../Assets/simongame.png";
import "../Style/Projects.css";

function Projects() {
    const [overlayOpacity, setOverlayOpacity] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            const aboutSection = document.getElementById('projects');
            const aboutSectionHeight = aboutSection.offsetHeight;
            const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

            const distanceFromTop = aboutSection.offsetTop - scrollPosition;

            if (distanceFromTop <= windowHeight) {
                const progress = 1 - distanceFromTop / aboutSectionHeight;
                setOverlayOpacity(progress);
            } else {
                setOverlayOpacity(0);
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);

    const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState(null);

    const projects = [
        { id: 1, title: "ShoeWarma", image: Showarma, description: "Description of Project 1" },
        { id: 2, title: "Simon Game", image: SimonGame, description: "Description of Project 2" },
    ];

    const handleImageClick = (projectId) => {
        setSelectedProject(projectId);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
        setSelectedProject(null);
    };

    return (
        <section id="projects" className="Projects-section">
            <div className="overlay" style={{ backgroundColor: `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${overlayOpacity})` }}></div>
            <div className="project-grid">
                {projects.map(project => (
                    <div key={project.id} className="project-card">
                        <h3>{project.title} </h3>
                        <img src={project.image} alt={project.title} onClick={() => handleImageClick(project.id)} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            {selectedProject && (
                <div className="modal" onClick={closeModal}>
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <h3>{projects[selectedProject - 1].title}</h3>
                        <img src={projects[selectedProject - 1].image} alt={projects[selectedProject - 1].title} />
                        <p>{projects[selectedProject - 1].description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </section>
    );
}

export default Projects;
```

This is the Css:

```
.project-card img {
    max-width: 55%;
    max-height: 55%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;


}

.project-card img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.project-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.project-card {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding-top: 60px;
}


.modal-content {

    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

i already console log the handleimgclick and it's work, everytime i click on img it console the id of the specific project.
i try to console log also the project array as well and everything is ok with it

Comment: There is `display: none;` in the styles for `.modal`

Comment: It should be 'none', just when i click on an image it will appear.
However I tried to change it again and it doesn't render as well.

Comment: There is no reason for it to be `none`. If you want it anyway you should change this style directly

Comment: @Mr.Blofer: *"It should be 'none'"* - Then what exactly are you looking to do?  If the element **should** be styled to not be shown, then the fact that the element is not shown is **by design**.  On the other hand, if the goal is to display the element then you'd want to re-style it to be displayed.  (Note that you don't need to rely on changing `display` styling to show/hide the element.  In the code shown you are only conditionally rendering the element anyway.)

Comment: What do you mean change it directly?
I tried now to erase the none and nothing happened.
also I try to change it from none to 'flex' and also it doesn't appear when I click on the image.
please be specific I try to figure it out for 5 hours :(

Comment: @Mr.Blofer: Can you update the question to include a runnable [mcve] which visibly demonstrates the problem?  Just describing what changes you've made won't get far.

Comment: @David, I thought that the condition that i wrote on the  '{selectedProject && ('
is making the modal to be rendered.
However I erase the display: none in my code and it doesn't change nothing.

Comment: I updated the question and now you can try to run it @David

Comment: @Mr.Blofer: Removing `display:none;` from the modal's styling [demonstrably works](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-margulis-zpyxnv?file=/src/Projects.js), making this essentially nothing more than a typo.  (Unless you can provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates a problem.)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-tree-czhm3w?file=/src/style.css removing `display: none` fixes everything

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you encapsulated your modal HTML in a conditional statement as an argument instead of as the result of the conditional statement. Something like this might work:

```
{
  selectedProject !== null ? (
    <div className="modal" onClick={closeModal}>
      <div className="modal-content">
        <h3>{projects[selectedProject - 1].title}</h3>
        <img src={projects[selectedProject - 1].image} alt={projects[selectedProject - 1].title} />
        <p>{projects[selectedProject - 1].description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>) : (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

This uses the ternary operator "? and :" for conditionally rendering your modal when selectedProject is not null or an empty div when selectedProject  is null, which seems to be what you want. [React docs have great coverage on this.](https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering) If you need more control over the conditional rendering or if you want more readable code, the docs also suggest using a function which returns conditional HTML. It is described more in depth in that same link to the React docs.

Comment: Where are you seeing this as being the problem? Looks like the `display` value is indeed the problem.